# creating an online enterprise wiki site collection is showing this endless message ""We're still working on it and it might take 24 hours.""

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, administration

We have an office 365 tenant, and i am trying to create a new enterprise wiki site collection @ `/sites/oursitename/`. but for more than 24 hours, I am still getting this error "We're still working on it and it might take 24 hours.", as follow:-

[image]

So I am not sure what is going on? Although when i tried to create a classic team site @ `/sites/oursitename2/` it worked well, where the classic team site got added after 10 minutes only!!.. so can anyone advice on this please?

One note i have:- Last week I have migrated our on-premises team site to our built-in root site (which is a classic team site), but the migration failed (where only part of the data got migrated), so I have removed the root site and i created a new root site collection of type classic team site, and i did the migration again, and it went well. So i am not sure if recreating the root site collection have any effect on the issue i am facing? Although i followed these steps when i deleted the root site collection https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb8e165b-df47-457c-af87-a02754b4c982/spo-root-site-recreation?forum=onlineservicessharepoint, and i removed the deleted site collection from recycle bin using this power-shell command:-

```
Connect-SPOService -url https://****-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $credential
Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/****/
```

I also tried to create a new site collection without template, as follow:-

[image]

and after 5 minutes the site got created correctly, then i navigated to the site and i chose the template, but after that i got this error:-

[image]

Error:-

[image]

Comment: We have seen this at multiple tenants the past day(s). Non-team sites takes forever to create. Only advice is to open tickets against MS so that they acknowledge the issue

Comment: @RobertLindgren thanks for the reply.. so it is a general problem inside Office 365 and not related to deleting the root site collection...

Comment: Yes it seems so. There are problems in CSOM aswell right now regrading site creation, possibly for the same reasons

Comment: @RobertLindgren I opened  a ticket with MS will see what they will say.. the issue that i am working on 2 tenants (test & live) ,, and for both tenants i have removed/re-added the root site collection and for both of them i am unable to create enterprise wiki site collection..

Comment: As long as there is a root site you should be fine

Comment: @RobertLindgren that what i assumed... actually i first recreate the root on test which worked well,, then i do the same on the live.... so seems it is a general problem not related to my case...

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure whether it is results by deleting root site collection.

You can contact Office 365 support to see if you can get more information there.

About how to create service requests to contact Office 365 support:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenkumar/archive/2013/07/18/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support.aspx